# Orthogonal basis with rational coefficients (Petersson inner product)

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, arithmetic-geometry, hecke-algebras

Let us consider the Petersson inner product $\left<-,-\right>:S_2(\Gamma_0(N))\times S_2(\Gamma_0(N))\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$,
$$\left<f,g\right>:=\int_{\Gamma_0(N)\backslash \mathbb{H}}\bar{f}g\,dxdy.$$

$\textbf{My question is:}$ Is there an orthogonal basis for $S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ with rational Fourier coefficients?

I have seen the proof that there exists a rational (and in fact integral) basis for $S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ as a complex vector space. Via Gram-Schmidt we can then modify this basis into an orthogonal one. However, since the inner product takes values in $\mathbb{C}$, this process may kill the rationality of such basis.

I think we may need something other than Gram-Schmidt. Perhaps we should use one of the basis that we know to be orthogonal and do some clever manipulations? Or maybe do some tricks with Hecke operators?

Sorry if this is a trivial question, I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: You mean the cusp forms with rational Fourier coefficients, right? Your question doesn't have to be obvious, the bilinear form $\Bbb{Q}^2\to \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2),b(x,y)=10 x_1y_1+10 x_2y_2+\sqrt2 x_1y_2+\sqrt2 x_2y_1$ doesn't have an orthogonal basis

Comment: Yes, I mean the space of cusp forms with rational Fourier coefficients. I will edit my question to make that more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question! Looking for an *orthonormal* basis is clearly hopeless, but an orthogonal basis doesn't seem impossible. Might be worth investigating first the case when $S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ is 2-dimensional and spanned by two normalised newforms which are Galois-conjugate to each other, e.g. $N = 23, 29$, or $31$.